# Core Data Migration versions

Tags: objective-c

When I create my second core data model and run the application everything is fine. But when I modify the second model, application is crashed, and I have to delete my app and run again. Is it normal? When I put my application's second version into the AppStore will it be OK or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You have altered your Core Data Model, and when you attempt to run the new model over the existing one in your previous build, it can't figure out how to migrate the old store to a new store with the new model; this is called a migration. A lightweight migration (meaning you don't have to write any custom migration logic) can be performed as long as you version your model for every set of model changes. When changes are made within a version and you install over a previous build, the migration fails and your app crashes.

For working in the simulator, it's normal to reset content and settings very often when messing with your core data model, but when shipping to the store, it's very important to be aware of model versions. Once you ship with Model Version 1, no more edits can be made to that model version. As soon as you ship with model 1, go ahead and create a new model that you can edit freely until your next ship date. Do this by selecting your xcdatamodelId file, and selecting Editor -> Add Model Version. The "based on model" is your current model. Once this is created, select your xcdatamodelId file again and in the file inspector, make sure you new model version is selected under the heading Model Version.

Doing this will allow you to use lightweight migrations and stop your crashes, and you data will migrate from your old store to the new one on installing an update. [Read here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) in the docs for more!